# Download a file in VB.NET without Internet Explorer

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio

My question may sound strange but I would like to know how to download a file from VB.NET without Internet Explorer.

I know:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(
    "http://www.cohowinery.com/downloads/WineList.txt",
    "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\WineList.txt")
```

But when he tries, he uses Internet Explorer to download it. The site where I downloaded my file is incompatible with Internet Explorer. So it doesn't download.

How do I download it with another web browser like, for example, Firefox?

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `WebClient` class. Then you're not using any web browser. I wasn't aware that the code you have used IE anyway, but I don't actually use that method so it's never come up. No, I'm not going to provide an "example". There are loads out there already, and you should also read the documentation for that class.

Answer (score 0):

Check ['WebClient.DownloadFile' method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=net-5.0).

A simple example you may need:

```
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password") ' If need be.
    client.DownloadFile(url, fileName)
```